# How to fix radio button not showing message box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make radio button and when I click button save and then my radio button not selected it can appear some message box.

```js
 private void btnSimpan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataPembeli p = new DataPembeli();
                p.Pembeli = txtPembeli.Text;
                p.AlamatKirim = txtAlamat.Text;
                p.Kuantitas = (int)kuantitasItem.Value;
                p.TglPesan = dtTglPesanan.Value;
                p.HasAsuransi = chkAsuransi.Checked;
                p.ItemOrdered= cmbItem.Text;
                foreach (Control c in grpbxMetodePengiriman.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is RadioButton)
                    {
                        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)c;
                        if (rb.Checked)
                        {
                            p.MetodePengiriman = rb.Text;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p.MetodePengiriman = "0";
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: What `MessageBox` _”is not showing”_ … ? … Also, the `foreach` loop and `if` statement looks odd. First it will only do ONE (1) iteration and exit/break the loop. Would it not be easier to simply check the radio button as opposed to looping through all the controls? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: then it can't be merged together?

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you mean by “merged together”… If you want to pop up a message box if a particular radio button is NOT checked when the save button is pressed, then, put a `MessageBox` in the else portion of the `if` statement. It is still not clear to me when you want to display the message box nor what you want to do AFTER the message box is displayed.

Comment: In other words, `if` the radio button is NOT checked, what do you want to do? The code “appears” to be creating a new `DataPembeli` object `p`… so what do you want to do with that `p` object if the radio button IS checked AND what do you to do with `p` if the radio button IS NOT checked?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be saying that you want to make sure that the user has checked a `RadioButton` in a group. If so, the best way is to use LINQ to get all the `RadioButtons` in the container and see if any are checked, e.g.

```cs
if (myContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(rb => rb.Checked))
{
    // A RadioButton in myContainer has been checked.
}
```

If you actually want to get the checked `RadioButton` and use it then you can do this:

```cs
var checkedRadioButton = myContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.Checked)

if (checkedRadioButton == null)
{
    // No RadioButton is checked.
}
else
{
    // Use checkedRadioButton here.
}
```

Based on your code, you could probably do this:

```cs
p.MetodePengiriman = myContainer.Controls
                                .OfType<RadioButton>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(rb => rb.Checked)
                                ?.Text ?? "0";
```

`FirstOrDefault` will either return a `RadioButton` reference or `null`. If the former, the `Text` property of that control will be used. If the latter, the `?.` operator will cause the whole expression to evaluate to `null` and then the `"0"` will be used instead.